# Writing Spark DataFrame to Hive table through AWS Glue Data Cataloug

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm using Spark 2.4.0 on EMR and trying to store simple Dataframe in s3 using AWS Glue Data Catalog. The code is below:

```
val peopleTable = spark.sql("select * from emrdb.testtableemr")
val filtered = peopleTable.filter("name = 'Andrzej'")
filtered.repartition(1).write.format("hive").mode("append").saveAsTable("emrdb.testtableemr")
```

**Above code works as expected- data is filtered and stored in s3 directory** that is linked with AWS Glue table emrdb.testtableemr. The issue I got is: although it works correctly it still throws below exception

```
scala> filtered.repartition(1).write.format("hive").mode("append").saveAsTable("emrdb.testtableemr")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.loadTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:843)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.loadTable(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:159)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.processInsert(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:259)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.run(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.CreateHiveTableAsSelectCommand.run(CreateHiveTableAsSelectCommand.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.createTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:465)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:444)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:400)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:163)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:175)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDatabasePath(Warehouse.java:172)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getTablePath(Warehouse.java:184)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getFileStatusesForUnpartitionedTable(Warehouse.java:520)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.updateUnpartitionedTableStatsFast(MetaStoreUtils.java:180)
  at com.amazonaws.glue.shims.AwsGlueSparkHiveShims.updateTableStatsFast(AwsGlueSparkHiveShims.java:62)
  at com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.GlueMetastoreClientDelegate.alterTable(GlueMetastoreClientDelegate.java:534)
  at com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSCatalogMetastoreClient.alter_table(AWSCatalogMetastoreClient.java:400)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.alterTable(Hive.java:497)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.alterTable(Hive.java:485)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadTable(Hive.java:1669)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_14.loadTable(HiveShim.scala:878)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:780)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:780)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:780)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:275)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:213)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:212)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:258)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.loadTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:779)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:845)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:843)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:843)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
  ... 74 more
```

I got same error using `insertInto` method:

```
filtered.repartition(1).write.mode("append").insertInto("emrdb.testtableemr")
```

Can you please help me understand meaning of this Exception in this context and suggest way how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Regards
Andrzej

Answer (score 8):

The issue is happening because it is missing s3 path in your dataframe writer statement. Passing s3 path as shown below will fix this issue.

```
val peopleTable = spark.sql("select * from emrdb.testtableemr")
val filtered = peopleTable.filter("name = 'Andrzej'")
filtered.repartition(1).write.option("path","s3://testbucket/testpath/").mode("append").saveAsTable("emrdb.testtableemr")
```

Comment: Which class do you reffer to? In `DataFrameWriter` there is no `saveAsTable` method with signature you suggested: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#saveAsTable-java.lang.String-
I'm looking at Spark 2.4.0. Can you please clarify?
Regards!

Comment: @awenclaw my bad!! I gave you pyspark example.I have updated the code now.

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesn't help. Acctually, if I do exactly as you pasted: `filtered.repartition(1).write.option("path","s3://testbucket/testpath/").mode("append").saveAsTable("emrdb.testtableemr")` than I got different error: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: The format of the existing table emrdb.testtableemr is `HiveFileFormat`. It doesn't match the specified format `ParquetFileFormat`.;`, but when I'm adding `.format("hive")` than I'm going back to orginal error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string`. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Btw, I'm creating table in Glue Data Catalog using crowler (if it changes anything)

Comment: Can you directly write it to a new table which already doesn't exists??

Comment: I'm not sure how to write to table "which already doesn't exists". I just created new table with glue crawler, read data from old table and save in new table- the the issue remain the same `Can not create a Path from an empty string`. However when I just store a file without going through Glue Data Catalog `filtered.repartition(1).write.format("json").mode("append").save("s3://awenclaw-emr-test/destDir/")` the data frame was stored correctly (no StackTrace and "_SUCCESS" file created)

Comment: @awenclaw for HiveFileFormat errir you need to add `spark.sql.sources.provider= parquet` as a parameter in Glue. I'm now having issues where it can't write a new schema `The column number of the existing table <glue_database>.<table_name>(struct<SCHEMA IS EMPTY>) doesn't match the data schema(<SCHEMA IS HERE>)`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and my solution was to go to the settings of the database in Glue Data Catalog ('emrdb' in this case for you) and add a Location URI (it can be a random one). Then I can create tables without specifying this LOCATION as I was doing before without Glue Data Catalog and everything is working fine.

It is described in the official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html

> Having a default database without a location URI causes failures when you create a table. As a workaround, use the LOCATION clause to specify a bucket location, such as s3://mybucket, when you use CREATE TABLE. Alternatively create tables within a database other than the default database.